# MySQL query returning rows from every user

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple search script to search a database which should return all the rows of data that match the search query that belong to that user, however my query (below) is returning rows from every user. Any idea how to fix this?

```
SELECT * FROM tablename 
WHERE title LIKE '%" . $q . "%' 
OR text LIKE '%" . $q . "%' 
AND user='$user'
```

**Side Note**: This is executed in PHP so the `$q` is the variable that holds the query.

Comment: `$user` is a PHP variable, right?

Comment: @BryanH yes it contains the username from a session variable (defined earlier)

Comment: i am sure you aware of sql injunction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
"SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE (title LIKE '%".$q."%' OR text LIKE '%".$q."%') AND user='$user'"
```

Comment: This works great for the null input value however if a space is entered either by itself "[SPACE]" or in a statement "word[SPACE]"... Nothing is returned.

Comment: @4cpukid, can you provide an example where nothing is returned by echoing the query string?

Comment: @Mike "[SPACE]" and anything that has a [SPACE] in it. So if I search "birds[SPACE]" even if there is not a second word it won't even return the rows with "birds".

Comment: @4cpukid also try `' or '1'='1`

Comment: @Stephen, that's not the query string. I mean the whole thing  including `SELECT * FROM` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Clear the $user variable of any white space before trying the SQL query

Comment: Why would white space affect it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php 
...
echo "SELECT * FROM tablename 
WHERE title LIKE '%" . $q . "%' 
OR text LIKE '%" . $q . "%' 
AND user='$user'";
```

And see what the output looks like.

Just as an aside, you can probably get away with

```
WHERE title LIKE '%$q%'
```

(i.e., not having to concatenate the query string). This will keep your code a bit cleaner and reduce errors (from missing a period/quote).